# Rewrite PostgreSQL to Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

if this possible to rewrite this PostgreSQL query to Django ORM with no raw SQL, i tried it by myself but i haven't succeeded.

Here is Fund's model

```
class Fund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=320, unique=True)
    fund_manager = models.CharField()
     ..............
```

And here is NAV's model

```
class NAV(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, verbose_name=_('NAV'))
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('date'))
    fund = models.ForeignKey('Fund', related_name='navs')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

And here is sql query that works and needs to be rewritten to Django ORM

```
select * from finance_fund ORDER BY(
  (select price from finance_nav where date='2016-11-08' and fund_id=finance_fund.id) / 
  (select price from finance_nav where date='2016-11-07' and fund_id=finance_fund.id)
)
```

So basically i need to order by division result of two simple queries of backward relations of Foreign key

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with raw SQL. Try something like:

```
qs = Fund.objects.annotate(x=RawSQL("""
    (select price from finance_nav where finance_fund.id=fund_id and date=%s limit 1) 
    / (select price from finance_nav where finance_fund.id=fund_id and date=%s limit 1)
    """,('2016-11-08', '2016-11-07'))).order_by('x')
```

Comment: So, would i be able to filter it later ?  For example `qs.filter()`

Comment: Yes. You can even refer to `.x`.

Comment: Wow, so it returns normal queryset instead of raw queryset (objects.raw) it seems for me that problem is solved.

Comment: I have unique dates per Fund's Navs so imho `limit 1` is redundant here.

Comment: So you can also add a unique_together = `(('fund', 'date'),)` to NAV :-)

Comment: Yes, i have added it, i wanted to say so in such case we don't need `limit 1` here.